# What is "Property chars is read only" in Visual Basic and how do I fix it?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

My goal is to do this: read the data from the file into the arrays, load the list box, calculate each student average and determine the letter grade, and calculate the class average:

**My declared variables (Global):**

Dim project, midterm, hw1, hw2, final, count, average As Integer

```
Dim letterGrade, lastName, firstName As String
Dim classAverage As Double
```

---

**My Code:**

Dim array1 As String() = New String(6) {}

```
    Dim streamreader1 As StreamReader = File.OpenText("grades.csv")
    count = 0
    classAverage = 0
    Do While (streamreader1.Peek() <> -1)
        array1 = Strings.Split(streamreader1.ReadLine(), ",", -1)
        firstName(count) = array1(0)
        lastName(count) = array1(1)
        lstNames.Items.Add(lastName(count) & ", " & firstName(count))
        hw1(count) = Convert.ToString(array1(2))
        hw2(count) = Convert.ToString(array1(3))
        project(count) = Convert.ToString(array1(4))
        midterm(count) = Convert.ToString(array1(5))
        final(count) = Convert.ToString(array1(6))
        average(count) = Math.Round(Math.Truncate((((((hw1(count) + hw2(count)) + (2 * project(count))) + (4 * (midterm(count) + final(count)))) / 12) + 0.5)))
        classAverage = (classAverage + ((((hw1(count) + hw2(count)) + (2 * project(count))) + (4 * (midterm(count) + final(count)))) / 12))
        Dim num1 As Integer = average(count)
        If (num1 >= 93) Then
            letterGrade(count) = "A"
        ElseIf (num1 >= 90) Then
            letterGrade(count) = "A-"
        ElseIf (num1 >= 87) Then
            letterGrade(count) = "B+"
        ElseIf (num1 >= 83) Then
            letterGrade(count) = "B"
        ElseIf (num1 >= 80) Then
            letterGrade(count) = "B-"
        ElseIf (num1 >= 77) Then
            letterGrade(count) = "C+"
        ElseIf (num1 >= 73) Then
            letterGrade(count) = "C"
        ElseIf (num1 >= 70) Then
            letterGrade(count) = "C-"
        ElseIf (num1 >= 67) Then
            letterGrade(count) = "D+"
        ElseIf (num1 >= 63) Then
            letterGrade(count) = "D"
        ElseIf (num1 >= 60) Then
            letterGrade(count) = "D"
        Else
            letterGrade(count) = "E"
        End If
        count = (count + 1)

    Loop
    classAverage = (classAverage / count)
    lstNames.SelectedIndex = 0
    PopulateLabels(0)
    streamreader1.Close()
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like `letterGrade` is a `String`, not an array of strings. You'll need to properly declare it as an array.

After your edit...

I'd recommend creating a `Student` class which contains the values from the text file. It would also contain methods for `CalculateAverage()` and `CalculateLetterGrade()` which execute against the object itself. Then dump each line from the textfile into a `Student` object, and add to a `List(Of Student)`. Once you have this list, you can loop through a nice simple list of objects to calculate the class average.

Something like this:

```
Public Class Student
    Public FirstName As String
    Public LastName As String
    Public Project As Integer
    ...
    Public Final As Integer

    Public Function CalculateAverage() As Integer
        ... ' Your calculation function
    End Function

    Public Function CalculateLetterGrade() As String
        ... ' Your calculation function
    End Function
End Class

Dim students As New List(Of Student)

'Inside your loop:
    Dim student As New Student()
    student.Project = Convert.ToString(array1(4))
    ... ' etc.
    students.Add(student)
```

At this point you'll have a simple collection of students, and you can loop through them, calculating your class average or whatever else you need.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new with Visual Basic.

Comment: You'll need to edit your question to include how you're creating that `letterGrade` in the first place. To create an empty array, the simplest way is `Dim letterGrade(5) as String` to get an array with 6 elements (indexes 0 through 5). But since you're starting with existing data, I'm guessing you don't have a fixed number to put there. There are a few other ways of creating an array, depending on your situation.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code. Could you maybe add some of this stuff for me please.